# How to parse JSON with PHP and Swift 5

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

I'm parsing JSON in my app via PHP, my messaging center was working fine but now it just stopped working. I'm using Swift 5, PHP and MySQL.

When I attempt to view the page in the app, I get a JSON error saying,

> 'The data cannot be read because it is not in the right format'.

Other pages using the same code are not having this problem.

I've tried different attributes to `JSONSerialization` but nothing has worked.

Swift 5 code to load messages from php

```
func loadMessages() {


    let username = user!["username"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.xxxx.com/messagecenter.php")!
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let body = "username=\(username)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if error == nil {

                do {

                    let json : NSDictionary? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let messages = parseJSON["messages"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                        print("Error while parseJSONing")
                        return
                    }
                   self.hhmessages = messages

                    for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {

                    let path = self.hhmessages[i]["ava"] as? String

                        if !path!.isEmpty {
                            let url = URL(string: path!)!

                            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) 
     let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)! 
     self.avas.append(image) // append found image to [images] var
                        } else {
                            let image = UIImage()

                            self.avas.append(image) 

                        }

                    }

      self.tableView.reloadData()


                } catch {
                    Helper().showAlert(title: "JSON Error", message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
                    return
                }

            } else {
            }

        })

        }.resume()

}
```

PHP Code

```
$access->connect();
$returnArray = array();
if (!empty($_REQUEST["uuid"]) && empty($_REQUEST["id"])) {


// STEP 2.1 Get uuid of post and path to post picture passed to this php file via swift POST
$uuid = htmlentities($_REQUEST["uuid"]);
//$path = htmlentities($_REQUEST["path"]);

// STEP 2.2 Delete post according to uuid
$result = $access->deleteMessage($uuid);

if (!empty($result)) {
    $returnArray["message"] = "Successfully deleted";
    $returnArray["result"] = $result;

} else {
    $returnArray["message"] = "Could not delete post";
}

 }
 else {

// STEP 2.1 Pass POST / GET via html encrypt and assign passed id of user to $id var
$username = htmlentities($_REQUEST["username"]);


// STEP 2.2 Select posts + user related to $id
$messages = $access->messageCenter($username);

// STEP 2.3 If posts are found, append them to $returnArray
if ($messages) {
    $returnArray['messages'] = $messages;
}

}
       //   STEP 3. Close connection
 $access->disconnect();


 // STEP 4. Feedback information
 echo json_encode($returnArray);

 ?>
```

The code should display the inbox for the user.

Comment: Check the response data from your PHP server, put `print(data! as NSData)` before `let json : ...` and see what's printed.

Comment: @OOPer I put print commas in and it's printing out a series of number <3c21444f 43545950 45206874 etc

Comment: `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` just after `if error == nil {` and see if it is a valid json.

Comment: That represents `"<!DOCTYPE ht"`, which may be the first part of the error page. Change the `print` to `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` and find what sort of error is happening from the HTML.

Comment: It looks like GoDaddy is blocking it as a fake bot page.

Comment: I resolved the Godaddy firewall issue and now my print out is showing the data but I'm still getting the json error showing in the app.

Comment: @OOPer it worked. Can you publish the answer so I can give you a vote.

Comment: You are the one who knows the right solution that solved your own issue. Please write an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue using the following steps:

1. Printed print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
2. Error message showed me that my file was being blocked by GoDaddy
3. Added my page to the whitelist on godaddy's security portal
4. It worked.